# How to programmatically set UUID, major ID, ... and other properties at 1m in Altbeacon format

Tags: android, ios, altbeacon

I am currently exploring retail advertising options. I am interested in AltBeacon as it is an open standard. I have a basic question, if someone can answer

How can I programmatically set UUID, major ID, minor ID, advertisements frequency, broadcasting power and RSSI at 1m in Altbeacon format on both (i) IOS devices and (ii) Android devices?

As Locate App is taking these values as variables from users, I guess they are inputting these values programmatically?!

Comment: I slightly reworded your question for readability, but well: I feel it is too broad, and doesn't fit the scope of this community. You should turn to the [help] to learn how/what to ask, and improve this question to be in the scope of this community.

Comment: are you asking how to configure these parameters on physical hardware beacons?  or are you asking how to set them on mobile phone beacon transmitters?

Comment: Initially I am checking with mobile phones before moving on to physical hardware beacons

Comment: See my answer to a related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52049451/1461050

Comment: Here I asked about initially "set" or input, that link is about "get" or parse :)

Answer (score 0):

If you wan to know how to do this with the Android Beacon Library, this is explained on the [sample code page](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html)

```
 Beacon beacon = new Beacon.Builder()
    .setId1("2f234454-cf6d-4a0f-adf2-f4911ba9ffa6")
    .setId2("1")
    .setId3("2")
    .setManufacturer(0x0118)
    .setTxPower(-59)
    .setDataFields(Arrays.asList(new Long[] {0l}))
    .build();
 BeaconParser beaconParser = new BeaconParser()
    .setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25");
 BeaconTransmitter beaconTransmitter = new BeaconTransmitter(getApplicationContext(), beaconParser);
 beaconTransmitter.setAdvertiseMode(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_MODE_LOW_LATENCY);
 beaconTransmitter.setAdvertiseTxPowerLevel(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_TX_POWER_HIGH);
 beaconTransmitter.startAdvertising(beacon);
```